# Pytorch RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict and Missing key(s) in state_dict

Tags: deep-learning, error-handling, pytorch, transfer-learning, rawimage

I am new at Pytorch and I was trying to test this GitHub project https://github.com/Srameo/LED/tree/main as per the instructions provided, but I am not able to resolve this error I tried all the pretrained models provided.

Thank you [ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlcqY.png)

There might be pretrained weights mismatch or model parameters set incorrectly. But I don't have much knowledge about that, So a detailed answer or relatable resources will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use the correct model architecture of your pre-trained weights

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.